# All values are true, although the values have been changed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have three input fields. Once for email, password and confirm password. If the user presses a button then a method `checkAll()` should be executed, this checks if the defaults for the fields are correct, if not another class should be assigned to the fields and the variable should be false.
The problem is, if all values are true then the default classes should be displayed again and `console.log("Everything ok");` should be output. However, if I reload the page and don't fill anything (everything should be set to false) then I still get an `Everything ok` in the console and all the variables are set to true, even though the method has set the values to false. Why is that?

**SignUp.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./SignUp.css";


function SignUp() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(true);
    const [value_email, setValue_email] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [passwordLength, setPasswordLenth] = useState(true)
    const [passwordValueEqual, setPasswordValueEqual] = useState('')
    const [passwordEqual, setPasswordEqual] = useState(true)
    const [emailExist, setEmailExist] = useState(false) 


    const checkEmail = async () => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/; 

        if (reg.test(value_email) === false) {
            console.log("E-Mail is wrong");
            setEmail(false);
        }
        else {
            setEmail(true);
        }
    };

    const checkPasswortLength = async () => {
        if(password.length < 5 ) {
            console.log("Passwort zu kurz");
            setPasswordLenth(false);
        }
        else{
            setPasswordLenth(true);
        }
    }

    const checkPasswortEqual = async () => {
        if(passwordValueEqual === password ) {
            setPasswordEqual(true);
            console.log("Passwörter sind gleich");
        }
        else{
            console.log("Passwörter sind ungleich");
            setPasswordEqual(false);     
        }
    }
   
    async function checkAll() {
        await checkEmail();
        await checkPasswortLength();  
        await checkPasswortEqual();
        if(email === true && passwordLength === true && passwordEqual === true ) {
            console.log("Everything ok");
            setEmailExist(true);

            
        }

    }

 




  
    return (
      <div className="SignUp">
        <div className="container" id="container">
            <div className="form-container sign-in-container">
                <form>
                <h2>Registriere dich jetzt</h2>
                <input type="email"  className={email ? 'input-form' : 'input-form-validation-wrong'} placeholder="E-Mail" onChange={event => setValue_email(event.target.value)} />
                <p className={email ? 'validation-email-right' : 'validation-email-wrong'}>E-Mail ist falsch</p>
                <input type="password" id="password" className={passwordLength ? 'input-form' : 'input-form-validation-wrong'} placeholder="Passwort" onChange={event => setPassword(event.target.value)} />
                <p className={passwordLength ? 'validation-password-short-right' : 'validation-password-short-wrong'}>Passwort ist zu kurz</p>
                <input type="password" id="password-confirm" className={ passwordEqual ? 'input-form' : 'input-form-validation-wrong'} placeholder="Passwort bestätigen" onChange={event => setPasswordValueEqual(event.target.value)} />
                <p className={passwordEqual ? 'validation-password-equal-right' : 'validation-password-equal-wrong'}>Passwörter stimmen nicht über ein</p>
                {emailExist === true &&
                    <p className='validation-password-equal-wrong'>E-Mail gibt es bereits</p>
                }
                    <div className='buttons-container'>
                        <button className="button-registration" type="button" onClick={checkAll}>Registrieren</button>
                    </div>
                    <a className="already-account" href="/login">Du hast bereits einen Account?</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        <div className="overlay-container">
        <div className="overlay">
            <div className="overlay-panel overlay-right">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default SignUp;
```

**SignUp.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
}

span {
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.buttons-container {
    
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.button-registration {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #5869FF;
    background-color: #5869FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
}



button:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button.ghost {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

form {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.input-form {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.input-form:focus {
    outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #5869FF;

}

.input-form-validation-wrong {
    
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.input-form-validation-wrong {
    
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #ff5858;
}

.input-form-validation-wrong:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #ff5858;
}

.input-form-validation-wrong::placeholder {
  color: #ff5858;

}

.input-remain {

}

.optional-buttons {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.already-account {
    color: #5869FF;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

.already-account:hover {
    color: #6a79fc;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.form-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 40%;
}

.sign-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.validation-wrong {
    color: #ff5858;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    text-align: left;
}

.validation-email-wrong {
    color: #ff5858;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    text-align: left;
}

.validation-email-right {
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.validation-password-short-wrong {
    color: #ff5858;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    text-align: left;
}

.validation-password-short-right {
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.validation-password-equal-wrong {
    color: #ff5858;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    text-align: left;
}

.validation-password-equal-right {
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}



.validation-right {
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}


.container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {
    0%, 49.99% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    50%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }
}

.overlay-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 40%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
    background-image: url('../../images/wallpaper.PNG');
    background-position: center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay {
    /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right top, #5869ff, #5c66ff, #6063ff, #6460ff, #685dff, #6d5bff, #715aff, #7658ff, #7c58ff, #8158ff, #8658ff, #8b58ff);*/
    /*background: linear-gradient(to right top, #5869ff, #5c66ff, #6063ff, #6460ff, #685dff, #6d5bff, #715aff, #7658ff, #7c58ff, #8158ff, #8658ff, #8b58ff);*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay {
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.overlay-right {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-right {
    transform: translateX(20%);
}

.social-container {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .overlay {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .overlay-container {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .form-container {
        max-width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    .optional-buttons {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
  }
```

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import SignUp from "./SignUp";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <SignUp></SignUp>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Reload Page

[image]

First Button click (the yellow mark is wrong)
[image]

Second Button click this time without the print statement everything okay
[image]

Comment: Is your console persisted?

Comment: No, the console also changes the values. Only after a second button click. Then the values are no longer all true and an everything okay is no longer output.

Comment: What I mean is that logs in your console _might_ be persisted _after_ refresh of the page.

Comment: No, the console is empty at the beginning and then after the button click I get something displayed

Comment: Have you tried setting the default values to `false` instead of `true`?

Comment: Sure, but if I set this to false from the beginning everything will be marked as false which should only happen if something is really wrong.

Comment: @Kazim checkout my answer, the problem is because if you call `checkEmail` it only updates the email outside the checkAll since we are not calling checkAll after the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling a function that updates a state on another function, the following code on the same function block won't use the updated value.

what you can do is return the updated value whenever you set it:

```
    const checkEmail = async () => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/; 

        if (reg.test(value_email) === false) {
            console.log("E-Mail is wrong");
            setEmail(false);
            return false; // add this one -------
        }
        else {
            setEmail(true);
            return true; // add this one --------
        }
    };
```

^^ do that for the other functions as well (checkPasswortLength, and checkPasswortEqual)

Then, on your checkAll:

```
    async function checkAll() {
        const emailCheck = await checkEmail();
        const passwordLengthCheck = await checkPasswortLength();  
        const passwordEqualCheck = await checkPasswortEqual();
        if(emailCheck === true && passwordLengthCheck === true && passwordEqualCheck === true ) {
            console.log("Everything ok");
            setEmailExist(true);
        }
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

We can't use setstate callback functions since the setstate is called on another function, One other way is to use `useEffect`.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if(email === true && passwordLength === true && passwordEqual === true ) {
            console.log("Everything ok");
            setEmailExist(true);
        }
    }, [])

    async function checkAll() {
        await checkEmail();
        await checkPasswortLength();  
        await checkPasswortEqual();
        // we removed the condition here
    }
```

this way you don't have to "return" the value and will automatically notify the user everytime everything is ok.

Comment: @I am L .. Is there any other way to solve this issue? Since its a asynch function, obviously variables update later. Can we use some callback logic here instead of returning true or false?

Comment: @MukulSharma I updated my answer and added an alternative.